# ESP32 powered over long lines with 230V

Tags: power, ac, emc, interference, 5v

I'm planning to put several Ethernet ESP32s with AMS1117 5 V to 3.3 V power converters and SHT31 temperature sensors around my house to report temperatures. They will be connected over Ethernet; power to the ESP32s will be delivered by free pairs in UTP cable.

Originally I planned to use PoE, but I found a big problem: the PoE converter emits too much heat and makes the SHT31 self-heating.

Could I just get rid of thePoE converters and power the ESP boards with 5 V from a central power supply, with some capacitor on the end of the wires?

Maximum distance from the Ethernet switch is 30 m and current drawn by the board is quite low (max. 200 mA), so voltage drop shouldn't be an issue.

What I'm worrying about is that Ethernet cables will placed along 230 V lines.
My house is a pure residential environment, no electric motors or any induction style devices, but I'm still worried about interference from the 230 V lines.

Should I worry?

Thank you very much for your answers!
It looks like i've calculated voltage drop incorrectly and you're right :/ I'll go with other solution for powering device, probably adding some 12V->5V converter on end.

Comment: Woudn't WiFi be an option? Or BLE. It's easier than routing ethernet cables everywhere. Powering the ESP32 would be also easier.

Comment: _"... so voltage drop shouldn't be an issue."_ - Are you sure? Have you done the math? If not, do the math.

Comment: Have you considered wiring the SHT31s by themselves?  It seems a terrific waste to put Ethernet out on location (100mA+ consumption) when all you need is some piddly ~1mA sensor. (I2C works poorly over distance, but a shielded cable, and/or differential interface, or MCU as perhaps a I2C-UART bridge, would do well here, at a tiny fraction of overall current consumption).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I worry?

Regarding data transmission, no worries, Ethernet is extremely robust.

CAT5 has a loop resistance of about 0.2 ohm/m (this is for both wires of one pair over 1m). So for 30m you get 6 ohms resistance on your power supply. With your quoted 200mA current draw, this will drop 1.2V, so you'll get 3.8V on the LDO input (assuming there is no reverse polarity protection diode).

AMS1117 won't work with such a low dropout. Besides, this LDO is really bad, it's slow, needs an expensive cap, tends to burn on overcurrent, etc. A good pinout-compatible replacement is LDL1117 from ST. It will deliver 3.3V from 3.8V input. When replacing AMS1117 with LDL1117, the 10µF tantalum output cap must be replaced with a 10µF MLCC. A side effect of the much improved transient response is much rarer crashes and reboots.

Note if you just want a temperature sensor, there are simpler solutions. DS18B20 works fine with 30m wires, and there are plenty of cheap Zigbee sensors on the market too.

Comment: _"No worries, Ethernet is extremely robust."_ - But the question isn't about Ethernet, it's about using Ethernet cabling for 5V power transmission alongside 230V. Op is (rightly) worried about interference. Your answer does not address that.

Comment: @marcelm If it helps, I will gladly note that "a solution exists". OP didn't provide any information to assess EMC performance of, so it seems a moot point to try and answer it here. If they want more detail in that direction, I would suggest they add that information to the question (or at this point as answer(s) exist, perhaps making it a new question).